# Prepend to nameless array in Redux reducer

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I get an array of objects from an API and store it in an `articleData` prop via Redux. The prop is stored like this:

[image: articleData Prop]

In my reducer I want to prepend to this array with another `articleData` object. The object I want to prepend is stored in `action.articleData` but I can't find a way to prepend this array without naming it. Here is my reducer code:

```
export function articleData(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ARTICLE_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
            return action.articleData;

        //HERE IS THE PROBLEM!
        case 'ARTICLE_POST_NEW_ARTICLE_SUCCESS':
            return {arr:[action.articleData, ...state]} 

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

It prepends the new object successfully. **Problem is: When I execute this code it changes the state from an array of objects to an array named "arr".** See picture:

[image]

I can't figure out how to just add to the array of objects without naming it something. If I remove the `arr:` from the reducer code it results in a syntax error.

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help me out! :)

Comment: Shouldn't `state.articleData` exist? `return {...state, articleData: [action.articleData, ...state.articleData] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of the `articleData` reducer is an array. In the `ARTICLE_POST_NEW_ARTICLE_SUCCESS` action handler, you create a new state, which is an object, with an `arr` property - `{arr:[action.articleData, ...state]}`.

Instead return a new array with the new `articleData`, and spread the `state` into it:

```
    case 'ARTICLE_POST_NEW_ARTICLE_SUCCESS':
        return [action.articleData, ...state]
```

In addition since the state of the reducer is an array, change the initial state to an empty array:

```
export function articleData(state = [], action) {
```

Comment: state is an object not an array

Comment: The state of this reducer is an array.

Comment: I don't think so: `state = {}` is the initial state.

Comment: The top level state of the store, is usually an object, but it can also be an array. This reducers state is the `articleData` array which he gets from the API. When updating it, he needs to return an array, and not an object.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. I love your explanation. I don't know why I was even trying to return an object anyways... I need to work on my javascript skills lol :P. Thanks again!

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda - thanks for the help. I've missed the initial state deceleration. Although it's not the problem, it should be an array. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @BrettMerrifield - not in the reducer's deceleration - `export function articleData(state = {}, action) {` :)

Comment: Oh shit i didn't even notice the `[]`... Makes a lot more sense lol. Thank you again! :)